# IntelliJ IDEA plugin dependency ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, plugins

I created plugin with the following dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'fluent-hc', version: '4.5.6'
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10'
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '26.0-jre'
```

and it is working perfect.

Then I added more dependencies:

```
compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.13.Final'
compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: '3.0.0'
compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.el', version: '3.0.0'
```

and it is working perfect when I tested plugin with runIde task on local.

When I added jar file to IDEA I got exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation

In both cases jar file does't contain any dependencies.

What did I miss?

---

UPDATE

6 years old question:

[How does Intellij IDEA manage plugin dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492301/how-does-intellij-idea-manage-plugin-dependencies)

Is it still valid? If so how I can put my dependencies in the plugin jar?

Im doing now:

`gradle clean buildPlugin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on response [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000930959-gradle-dependencies) I need to submit zip file instead of jar. Zip contains all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Update build.gradle

```
jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```